# Python: speed up matrix coordinate mapping through iteration

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, coordinates

I'm trying to get this code to run as fast as possible and at the moment is very inefficient.

I have a 4D matrix of scalar data. The 4 dimensions correspond to latitude, longitude, altitude and time.  The data is stored in a numpy array and its shape is (5,5,30,2).

In 4 different lists I am keeping the "map" for each axis, storing what value corresponds to each index.  For example, the map arrays could look like:

```
mapLatitude = [45.,45.2,45.4,45.6,45.8]
mapLongitude = [-10.8,-10.6,-10.4,-10.2,-10.]
mapAltitude = [0,50,100,150,...,1450]
mapTime = [1345673,1345674]
```

This means that in the data matrix, the data point at location 0,1,3,0 corresponds to
Lat = 45, Lon = -10.6, Alt = 150, Time = 1345673.

Now, I need to generate a new array containing the coordinates of each point in my data matrix.

So far, this is what I've written:

```
import numpy as np

# data = np.array([<all data>])
coordinateMatrix = [ 
   (mapLatitude[index[0]],
    mapLongitude[index[1]],
    mapAltitude[index[2]],
    mapTime[index[3]] ) for index in numpy.ndindex(data.shape) ]
```

This works, but takes quite a long time, especially when the data matrix increases in size (I need to use this with matrices with a shape like (100,100,150,30) ).

If it helps, I need to generate this coordinateMatrix to feed it to `scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator` .

Any suggestions on how to speed this up?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn your lists into `ndarray`'s you can use broadcasting as follows:

```
coords = np.zeros((5, 5, 30, 2, 4))
coords[..., 0] = np.array(mapLatitude).reshape(5, 1, 1, 1)
coords[..., 1] = np.array(mapLongitude).reshape(1, 5, 1, 1)
coords[..., 2] = np.array(mapAltitude).reshape(1, 1, 30, 1)
coords[..., 3] = np.array(mapTime).reshape(1, 1, 1, 2)
```

For more general inputs something like this should work:

```
def makeCoordinateMatrix(*coords) :
    dims = len(coords)
    coords = [np.array(a) for a in coords]
    shapes = tuple([len(a) for a in coords])
    ret = np.zeros(shapes + (dims,))
    for j, a in enumerate(coords) :
        ret[..., j] = a.reshape((len(a),) + (1,) * (dims - j - 1))
    return ret

coordinateMatrix = makeCoordinateMatrix(mapLatitude, mapLongitude,
                                        mapAltitude, mapTime)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
However, it doesn't work… I keep getting: `ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0`

It seems like it's an issue related to axis=-1 ?

Comment: Bummer, `np.concatenate` doesn't do broadcasting. I have modified the code, and this time tested it!

Comment: I get this error now… `ValueError: output operand requires a reduction, but reduction is not enabled`
I've been looking online but found nothing about it! Any ideas?